# How to use properly BigInteger methods in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to do the factorial of a number using this method:

```
public static BigInteger factorial (long n) {
    BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
    for(BigInteger i = BigInteger.TWO; i.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(n)) >= 0; i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        result = result.multiply(i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

and I'm asking why te result stays always 1 (BigInteger.ONE) ?

Comment: What behaviour are you expecting here?

Comment: result = result * i;

Comment: At the end result must be n!

Comment: **By far**, the best way to understand this kind of thing is to use the debugger built into your IDE to step through the code statement by statement.

Comment: Did you debug?  How many times does the loop actually execute?

Comment: This drops out so nicely in an old-fashioned language like C++. Java: one step forward, two steps back. Without operator overloading, this is unreadable. Upvoted for sympathy,.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the definition of [compareTo(T o)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T))

> **Returns**: a **negative integer**, zero, or a positive integer as this object is **less than**, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

You are using `>= 0` meaning *continue looping while `i` is **greater than** `n`*.

You probably need `<= 0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
i.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(n)) >= 0
```

is wrong, instead use

```
i.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(n)) <= 0
```